# Symfony 2 + FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I read the manual for FOSUserBundle and i can't override my own template. I used solutions with create new folder in "app/resources".

I created new template for login and placed in the direction /app/resources/FOSUserBundle/Security/login.html.twig but isn't work.

Someone know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the views directory:

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/**views**/Security/login.html.twig

Docs:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Comment: no i don't :) i only forgot to write. My directory is "\app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\Security"